# Remove the (1) when saving duplicate files in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, duplicate

So when i save a duplicate file from the net, the system automatically adds a (1) right at the end, before the extension and I have no idea if I can change it.

How do i keep the original file name so I can overwrite the existing one without manually removing the (1)?

Can it be done?

[image]

Comment: are you sure? in windows 7, it prompts you [this](http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1081/576581358_888090e76a.jpg) normally

Comment: @Sickest Not when you download it from the net.

Comment: ok? your question says windows 7, this is a Browser issue. What browser are you using? re-write your question, cause in its current state you're going to get no where.

Comment: I see you edited your question. And you still aren't mentioning the browser.

Comment: this can't be possible you have 6,000 rep in stackoverflow, and clueless how to ask a question in SU.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest option I see is to just click the file you want to overwrite (which auto-names the file you download to the same name as the file you click), and thereafter click "overwrite". This saves you a couple of seconds compared to manually erasing the " (1)". The Google Chrome browser has no option for it.